# How to make the database hit for every 10 min or 5 min using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function that needs to make a database hit for every 5 or 10 min to fetch the latest records from the database. If we make a DB hit for every 5 or 10 min will the performance issues arise?

what is the best way to achieve this? Below is my jquery code.

```
$(function () {
        debugger;
        /*setInterval(function () {*/
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: baseURL + "api/Controller/Method?Param1=" + P1 + "&Param2=" + P2,
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        if (item != null) {
                            for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                                debugger;
                                if (P1 == "") {
                                    $('.swiper-wrapper').append('<div class="swiper-slide"> ' + P1 + '</div>');
                                } else {
                                    $('.swiper-wrapper').append('<div class="swiper-slide"> ' + P1 + '<br />' + P2 + '</div>');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                        spaceBetween: 30,
                        slidesPerView: 1,
                        slidesPerColumn: 1,
                        centeredSlides: true,
                        autoplay: false,
                        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
                        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev'
                    });
                }
            });
        /*}, 25 * 1000);      */
    });
```

Comment: `setInterval()` is the keyword. You already have that in your code, but it's commented out. So what's the problem?

Comment: This type of question is out of scope for SO.com because you're not asking about a specific issue with your code, but rather you're looking for _opinions_ about how your code functions. That being said, the one improvement I'd suggest is to add some sort of server-side protection (CSRF?) that is returned with your ajax request (along with the updated data). Then you can implement some session logic to only actually query the DB if the token is valid (or if it's >5 minutes old). That way, you're protected against some spamming if a user manually changes the timeout from 5 mins to 5 seconds.

Comment: Performance issues: it depends on your server equipment, memory, CPU, disk speed, network speed, the complexity of your query, clients accessing the db simultaneously etc.  That being said, normally hitting a database every 5-10 min is not a problem. Instead of querying every 5-10 min, maybe it is better to look into push messaging techniques instead to avoid polling even if there is no new data? Depending on your technology there is plenty of libraries out there that will do this - I have good experience with https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/signalr

Comment: Yes, I had used set interval but the problem is it is getting refreshed every 10 sec when I had kept the swiper in the middle of the record it should take me to the first record which is not happening. Assume that I have 6 records and I was at 4th record now my swiper would be enabled on the left-hand side and right-hand side and after the refresh, I should show the first record again which is not happening getting refreshed but getting stayed at 4th record only.